# JavaFX HTMLEditor Bug?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to use `JavaFX` [`HTMLEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) in my application, but I seem to have run into a problem. I selected all the cells in a table and tried to left-align the data using the `left-align` button. I could get it to work for individual cells but not after `CTRL-A` and then the `left-align` button. Is this a bug or is this expected behavior. The other align buttons seem to work after `CTRL-A`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class HTMLEditorTest extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        String htmlString = "<!doctype html>\n"
                + "<html lang=\"en\">\n"
                + " <head>\n"
                + "     <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n"
                + "\n"
                + "     <title>HTMLEditor Test</title>\n"
                + "     <meta name=\"description\" content=\"HTMLEditor Test\">\n"
                + "     <meta name=\"author\" content=\"SitePoint\">\n"
                + " </head>\n"
                + "\n"
                + " <body>\n"
                + "     <table style=\"width:100%\">\n"
                + "         <tr>\n"
                + "             <th>Firstname</th>\n"
                + "             <th>Lastname</th> \n"
                + "             <th>Age</th>\n"
                + "         </tr>\n"
                + "         <tr>\n"
                + "             <td>Jill</td>\n"
                + "             <td>Smith</td> \n"
                + "             <td>50</td>\n"
                + "         </tr>\n"
                + "         <tr>\n"
                + "             <td>Eve</td>\n"
                + "             <td>Jackson</td> \n"
                + "             <td>94</td>\n"
                + "         </tr>\n"
                + "     </table>\n"
                + " </body>\n"
                + "</html>";

        HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
        htmlEditor.setHtmlText(htmlString);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(htmlEditor);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 700);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Whether it’s a bug is arguable.  What’s happening is that after Ctrl-A, the entire `<table>` is aligned as a single element.  Notice how the cursor is a different size after you change the alignment.

Comment: Does that explain why when you change the alignment, and you press `left-align` again, it does not `left-align`? The other three alignment buttons seem to work when all of the table fields are selected.

Comment: Yes, I think it believes that the table is already left-aligned.  It’s not apparent because of the `width:100%`.